# Schematic review for my ESP32 based design project

Tags: schematics, esp32, schematic

I am seeking some feedback for my schematic. I am designing a wearable device using an ESP32. It is my first time doing a schematic so I might have done some things wrong.

The first image is the ESP32, it has 3 buttons and 2 LEDs connected to GPIOs. I am using only a power button for boot and firmware download.

[image: ESP32]

The second image is for my power management. I am using an [MCP73871](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-DS20002090F.pdf) since I will have a battery for the device. I have a buck/boost converter to go from 5 V to 3.3 V and an LDO to go from 3.3 V to 1.8 V.

[image: Power Management]

The third image contains my 3 sensors (2 are using I2C and 1 is SPI).

[image: Sensors]

The final image is the micro USB port and the [CP2102N](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/cp2102n-datasheet.pdf) USB to UART bridge. I will be using 500 mA for charging and I only want it powered from the USB.

[image: USB-to-UART]

I might have done something wrong here with the connections from the MCP73871, so if anything stands out let me know. I would greatly appreciate any feedback on things that I might have missed or not done properly. Thank you.

Comment: You've tied 3.3V directly to SCL on that second page. Definitely not right. R18 and R19 also look wrong.

Comment: @Polynomial Yes I see, I will fix that. I will also double check R18 and R19 but I believe those values were shown in the datasheet.

Comment: You have both transorbs on page 4 connected to D+.   You surely mean for one of them to connect to D-

Comment: What's "EXT_5V"?  That diode on page 4 might be backwards.  The whole thing there might be off (5V coming from USB).  What's the intention and purpose of that bit of the circuit?

Comment: @KyleB Yes I fixed that connection. For the zener diode I took it from the ESP32 devkit schematic where it is wired like that. Should I remove it? Thanks

Comment: I see it on DEVKITC schematic https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/ESP32-Core-Board-V2_sch.pdf   That looks like it's meant to enable the ESP dev kit board to be powered by either the USB or some other 5V source.  The diode prevents one source from backfeeding into the other.   What's your power source for the final product... a battery???   Didn't see it glancing through your schems..   Do you want it to be able to power from USB and battery, or something else???